# Vector that can hold three data types using std::pair

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair

```
vector< pair<pair<int, string> >, string> v;
```

Also mention how to access them using 'first' and second'.
Is it even possible to do this or is "union" or "structure" the only way to create vector that can hold more than two data types?

Comment: Are you looking for a `std::pair` that holds three values? In that case see [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

Comment: having a pair, with a pair wihin it is no problem, but perhaps a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) is more relevant here.

Comment: Is it possible to sort them if tuple is used?

Comment: @DeepakKumarG just as well as with a pair. In fact tuple is a generalization of `std::pair`.

Comment: I would not use a `tuple` if you need to sort. In fact, a lot of things become more difficult when you switch to a tuple. Use a small struct for your triplet instead.

Comment: BTW, you have a typo with misplaced `>`.

Comment: Thanks all,can someone tell how can it be done using std::vector and std::pair itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector< std::pair<std::pair<int, std::string>, std::string> > v;` is possible, with

```
v[0].first.first = 42;
v[1].first.second = "hello";
v[2].second = "world";
```

`std::tuple` is a good alternative:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, std::string, std::string>> v = /*..*/;

std::get<0>(v[0]) = 42;
std::get<1>(v[0]) = "Hello";
std::get<2>(v[0]) = "World";
```

A proper structure allow to give semantic

```
struct Person
{
    int age;
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
};

std::vector<Person> persons = /*...*/;

persons[0].age = 42;
persons[0].firstName = "John";
persons[0].lastName = "Doe";
```

Comment: std::get<0>(v[0]) = 42;
std::get<1>(v[0]) = "Hello";
std::get<2>(v[0]) = "World";

But Iam not able to assign values got from the input

int n;
cin>>n;

get<0>(v[0])=n;

Gives seg fault.

Comment: Thanks. You convinced me that going to a POD struct is better than messing around with tuples.... at least for my application.